# Unable to create a TPH using Fluent API on EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api, tph

I modeling a Google Forms-like project. The bellow entities are pretty simple and straightforward (I guess), as follows.

Question types:

```
// Base class for any kind of question
public abstract class Question : Bean
{
    public string Statement { get; set; }
}

// Visual questions are questions where images are answers.
public class VisualQuestion : Question
{
    public virtual VisualAnswer Answer { get; set; }
}

// Discursive questions are questions where big texts are answers.
public class DiscursiveQuestion : Question
{
    public virtual DiscursiveAnswer Answer { get; set; }
}

// Objective questions are questions that can have multiple answers,
// where each of them should be no bigger than 1 character.
public class ObjectiveQuestion : Question
{
    public virtual List<ObjectiveQuestionOption> Options { get; set; }
}

// Options for objective questions.
public class ObjectiveQuestionOption : Question
{
    public int ObjectiveQuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectiveQuestion Question { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectiveAnswer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer types:

```
public abstract class Answer : Bean
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}

public class DiscursiveAnswer : Answer
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public virtual DiscursiveQuestion Question { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectiveAnswer : Answer
{
    public char Answer { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectiveQuestion Question { get; set; }
}

public class VisualAnswer : Answer
{
    public byte[] Blob { get; set; } // Image answer

    public virtual VisualQuestion Question { get; set; }
}
```

Where Bean is:

```
public abstract class Bean 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For the questions I could have, instead, a single `Question` object and a `QuestionOption` for the objective questions. If this is it, we would need all the 3 `Answer` objects inside `Question`, which doesnt sound right to me (one would need to recognize the question type and then access its answer member accordingly, like the `is` and `as` casts). For a workaround, I decided to split questions into 3 objects, defined above, and have individual Answer members, using the [TPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance) approach.

Everything seems to work with only 1 condition: all the fluent API settings must be done within the `void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` of the `DbContext` class (I have overridden it). This is a problem because I'm sepparating all my configs for each entity object and added them like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Approach 1: This works
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Map<DiscursiveQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("D")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Map<ObjectiveQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("O")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Map<VisualQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("V")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");

    // Approach 2: This does not work: it complains that 2 of the 3 entities cant share the TB_QUESTION table because "they are not in the same type hierarchy 
    // or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them" (???).
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VisualQuestionConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration());
}
```

These are the configuration objects:

```
public abstract class QuestionConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : Question
{
    public QuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Statement).HasColumnName("STATEMENT");
    }
}

public class DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration : QuestionConfiguration<DiscursiveQuestion>
{
    public DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("D")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    }
}

public class VisualQuestionConfiguration : QuestionConfiguration<VisualQuestion>
{
    public VisualQuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("V")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    }
}

public class ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration : QuestionConfiguration<ObjectiveQuestion>
{
    public ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("O")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    }
}
```

Why does approach 1 work while 2 doesnt?

**EDIT:**

I removed the configuration inheritance and it "almost" worked (see below). Like this:

```
public class QuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Question>
{
    public QuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Statement).HasColumnName("STATEMENT");

        // Configures the TPH
        Map<VisualQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TYPE").HasValue("Visual").HasMaxLength(10));
        Map<ObjectiveQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TYPE").HasValue("Objective").HasMaxLength(10));
        Map<DiscursiveQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TYPE").HasValue("Discursive").HasMaxLength(10));

        ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    }
}

public class DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration : Configuration<DiscursiveQuestion>
{
    public DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration()
    {
    }
}

public class VisualQuestionConfiguration : Configuration<VisualQuestion>
{
    public VisualQuestionConfiguration()
    {
    }
}

public class ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration : Configuration<ObjectiveQuestion>
{
    public ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration()
    {
    }
}

public class ObjectiveQuestionOptionConfiguration : Configuration<ObjectiveQuestionOption>
{
    public ObjectiveQuestionOptionConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.Question).WithMany(p => p.Options).HasForeignKey(p => p.ObjectiveQuestionId);

        Property(p => p.ObjectiveQuestionId).HasColumnName("ID_OBJECTIVE_QUESTION");
        Property(p => p.Statement).HasColumnName("STATEMENT"); // <--- This doesnt get mapped! :(

        ToTable("TB_OBJECTIVE_QUESTION_OPTION");
    }
}
```

And registered them like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Approach 1: This works
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Map<DiscursiveQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("D")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Map<ObjectiveQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("O")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Map<VisualQuestion>(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("V")).ToTable("TB_QUESTION");

    // Approach 2: This does work too, however ObjectiveQuestionOption* does not inherit the statement column
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuestionConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuestionOptionConfiguration());
}
```

Comment: Some things like `QuestionConfiguration<T>` class are redundant, but doesn't hurt. Can we see the non generic `QuestionConfiguration` class?

Comment: What do you mean its redundant and doesnt hurt? There's no sort of `QuestionConfiguration` non-generic class...

Comment: Then what is in there `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuestionConfiguration());`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It actually never existed (that was actually something else, nvm). I edited my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first approach tells EF to treat the base abstract class `Question` as entity (the `modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()` call) while the second doesn't.

You need to create and register a separate configuration for `Question`. Since you would configure all the common properties there, the `QuestionConfiguration<T>` class is redundant.

Here is the correct implementation of the second approach.

Configurations:

```
public class QuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Question>
{
    public QuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Statement).HasColumnName("STATEMENT");
        ToTable("TB_QUESTION");
    }
}

public class DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DiscursiveQuestion>
{
    public DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("D"));
    }
}

public class VisualQuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<VisualQuestion>
{
    public VisualQuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("V"));
    }
}

public class ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ObjectiveQuestion>
{
    public ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p => p.Requires("TP_QUESTION").HasValue("O"));
    }
}
```

Registering:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuestionConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VisualQuestionConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ObjectiveQuestionConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DiscursiveQuestionConfiguration());
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks A LOT for helping out. I've been struggling with it for almost a week now. This does work, but lies in another second problem (as mentioned in my edit)... I'm accepting your answer because it does answer the original question. If you dont mind, could you please update your answer to fix the second question? I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome. But now you seem to be mixing TPH with TPT, is that your intent? i.e. `ObjectiveQuestionOption` is sharing the TPH from its base `ObjectiveQuestion` (TPH), but also the additional columns go to another table `TB_OBJECTIVE_QUESTION_OPTION` (TPT).

Comment: Because if that's the case, it's normal to not map the common `Statement` column to the new table because it will be taken from the base table.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the case. The reason I chose configs inheritance (along generics) was due to the `Answer` configs, that use TPT (I didnt mention them because theyre not the case). But... suppose `Question` has only 1 member and we remove his mapping from `QuestionConfiguration`, what will be the point to have it? It's unclear to me, could you enlighten me up with an example?

Comment: Once a class is identified as entity, even if you don't include specific mapping for a property, it's mapped by convention to the corresponding base table and cannot be remapped to another table. If you indeed `Ignore` it in the base entity, then you cannot map it in any derived entity. Hence it's better to map at every level of the hierarchy only the declared properties.

Comment: Hi, Ivan! I tried many ways: mapped the `Statement` in every 3 derived question config and removed from the base class; I tried making it abstract and/or virtual in the base class and overrode it in every subclass, so that EF would think of it as a new member (I was wrong); and a few others. The only one that made it work was to create a `statement` private member (lowercase) and created an "alias" to it (https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/26/code-first-data-annotations-on-non-public-properties/). Then I overrode the `Statement` to access the `statement`. I havent actually tested it, though.

Comment: This might work, but frankly I wouldn't rely/use it. It's so error prone to try tusing a (non mapped) property brought up by intellisense in L2E queries and get the frustrating runtime exceptions. I think you are trying to put too much business/domain logic in something which is supposed to represent the store model. Just an opinion based on my experience with EF :)

Comment: Really? Basically, that's what I have done: https://pastebin.com/PCJA5W64. Does this change your mind? (I have very few experiences with EF and C# overall)
What do you suggest otherwise?

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, it might work. So as I understand, I works, but that doesn't change my opinion, because once you try to use `Question.Statement` in some `IQueryable<Question>` query for projection and/or filter, you'll get runtime exception. I personally would keep the column in the base table. But it's up to you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155846/discussion-between-yves-henri-and-ivan-stoev).